# Error in launching Java application on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, jar, cplex

I just installed Eclipse (2020 version) and IBM ILOG CPLEX (12.6.9 version), on Windows 10, to run a Java code that I already have.

The code uses Java API of CPLEX, so I followed [these few instructions (on CPLEX Official Page)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/set_up/Eclipse.html?view=embed) - they explains to set a `jar` and a `dll` filepaths - to set up Eclipse for using Java API of CPLEX.

I followed those steps, but when I launch the execution I get this error:

`Error: Unable to initialize main class Scheduler_1 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ilog/concert/IloNumExpr`

**Additional information:**
After navigating to `Run > Run Configurations ... > Java Application`, and selecting `Arguments tab`, if I click on `Show Command Line`, a dialog, which shows this output lines, appears (I don't know if it's correct):

```
`C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\Downloads\eclipse-java-2020-12-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507\jre\bin\javaw.exe`

`-Djava.library.path=CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/bin/x64_win64`

`-Dfile.encoding=Cp1252`

`-p "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\lib\cplex.jar"`

`-classpath "C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\eclipse-workspace\proj1\bin"`

`-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages Scheduler_1`
```

Is there anyone who know which could be the cause of the error which I encounter?

---

**To add more details:** these are the steps I followed:

1. Download of Eclipse 2020-12 ".zip" file and saved in "Download" folder, and download of CPLEX 12.6.9 "exe" file
2. Extract Eclipse 2020-12 "zip" into a folder (with the same name of the "zip") inside "Download", then I install both Eclipse and CPLEX (on Windows 10), by double-clicking on their respective "exe" files
3. Open Eclipse, and created a new Eclipse Java Project, called `proj1`
4. Added four ".java" source files (copy-pasted from another folder of my PC) inside `proj1/src/`
5. On Eclipse GUI:

   - `Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries`
   - When the dialog appears, click the button `Add External JARs`
   - Then after browsing the location, I select the file named `cplex.jar`.
6. On Eclipse GUI:

   - `Run > Run Configurations ... > Java Application`
   - When the dialog appears, I go to the `Main tab`, and select my `Main Class` (called `Scheduler_1`)
   - Then , I go to the `Arguments tab`, I select `VM arguments`, and add the path to the CPLEX library, so in my case:
     `-Djava.library.path=CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/bin/x64_win64`, which is the path to `cplex1290.dll`
7. I run the Java application, and I get the error:

`Error: Unable to initialize main class Scheduler_1 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ilog/concert/IloNumExpr`

Besides, `IloNumExpr` is not even used in my code, and, anyway, it is contained in `cplex.jar` (I checked by myself).

**Other details:** this is the `directory structure` of my project (which I could see from `Package Explorer`, which is part of the Eclipse `Workspace`):

- `proj1`

  - `src`

    - `(default packages)`: it contains four ".java" files (which I copy-pasted from another folder of my PC)
  - `JRE System Library`
  - `Referenced Library`: it contains `cplex.jar` (external library added by me)

Comment: Hi @howIger! I already showed it in the section "Additional information" of my question above..do you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it seems I solved my issue!
I post here what works for me for anyone who will encounter the same error.

I navigated to `Project -> Properties -> Build Path`, then I clicked on `Dependencies Tab` and I removed `cplex.jar` from `Modulepath Entries` and I added it to `Classpath Entries`.

Now, the previous error is solved.

Comment: Moving `cplex.jar` from the Modulepath to the Classpath via drag and drop should work also. A JAR containing a `module-info.class` might behave differently than on the Classpath and as module (with or without `module-info.class`) it must not contain the same package than in another module (whereas everything on the Classpath is handled as one module, the unnamed module).